# Negative accuracy numerics ( 0``-128 notation )

Tags: numerics, syntax, precision-and-accuracy

What does it mean to have a negative accuracy number?

I understand ``` 0``128 ``` to mean "the number zero to 128 decimal points". Mathematica corroborates this:

```
In[1]:= 0``128 < 1
(* Out[1]= True *)
In[2]:= 0``128 < 0
(* Out[2]= False *)
In[3]:= Accuracy[0``128]
(* Out[3]= 128. *)
```

But then I have no idea what "negative accuracy" is:

```
In[1]:= 0``-128 < 1
(* Out[1]= False *)
In[2]:= 0``-128 > 1
(* Out[2]= False *)
In[3]:= 0``-128 == 1
(* Out[3]= True *)     (* Why????? *)
In[4]:= Accuracy[0``-128]
(* Out[4]= -128. *)
```

Context: these values are showing up in a system of ~10000 equations, as the result of computing 100s of expressions of the form

$$ \sum_i \frac{\textrm{numer}}{\textrm{denom}} \textrm{basis}_i, $$

where both numer and denom are randomly generated complex numbers, with 200 digit precision. I then collect coefficients of the (symbolic) $\textrm{basis}_i$'s to form algebraic equations.

The ``` 0``128 ``` objects appear in only a handful of the total number of equations, so I don't yet know what causes the ``` 0``-128 ```'s to appear.

Comment: From the docs: "...The accuracy of a number can be negative, indicating that all the correctly known digits are to the left of the decimal point..."

Comment: Ah, thanks @ciao. I "ctrl+f" ' d through every page (except that one apparently). It's [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html), for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer:

> From the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html): "...The accuracy of a number can be negative, indicating that all the correctly known digits are to the left of the decimal point..." – ciao May 6 '15 at 0:29

In other words, the error in ``` 0``a ``` is at most `10^-a`.  So ``` 0``-128 ``` represents a numeric quantity at most `10^128` in magnitude.

Example:

```
N[10^148 (1 + 9*^-21), 20] - 10^148 // InputForm
(*  0``-128.  *)
```

And the error is less than `10^128`:

```
10^148 * 9 * 10^-21 // N
(*  9.*10^127  *)
```